# Camlex query on dropdown list

Tags: c#, list, dropdownlistfor

I've a problem on a camlex query : i've 2 lists on 2 dropdowns with a lookup on the second list.
I want filter the second dropdown when i select an item on the first dropdown.

For the first dropdown :

```
DropDownList JobsList = new DropDownList();
                    JobsList.SelectedIndexChanged +=
                            new EventHandler(JobsList_SelectedIndexChanged);

protected void JobsList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPList jobs = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Jobs"];
            string filter = string.Empty;
            if (this.JobSelector.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                filter = this.JobSelector.SelectedItem.Text;
            }            
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery
            {                
                Query = Camlex.Query().Where(x => (((string)x["Jobs"]).Contains(filter))).ToString()
            };

            SPListItemCollection items = jobs.GetItems(query);

        }
```

I've a problem for the query on the second dropdown :

```
using (SPWeb clientWeb = clientSite.RootWeb)
                {
                    string filter = string.Empty;
                    if(this.JobSelector.SelectedItem != null)
                    {
                        filter = this.JobSelector.SelectedItem.Text;
                    }

                    SPList subTypeList = clientWeb.Lists["SubTypes"];
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = Camlex.Query().Where(x => (((string)x["Jobs"]).Contains(filter))).ToString();

                    foreach (SPListItem subtype in subTypeList.GetItems(query))
                    {
                        this.subTypeSelectorID.Items.Add(new ListItem(subtype.Title, subtype.ID.ToString()));
                    }
                }
```

I don't understand why the query isn't good :

```
Query = Camlex.Query().Where(x => (((string)x["Jobs"]).Contains(filter))).ToString()
```

I try with another method but without success

```
   <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='Title' />
      <FieldRef Name='Jobs' />
   </ViewFields>
   <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='Jobs' />
         <Value Type='Lookup'>Authorizations</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Comment: are you getting correct value in - filter = this.JobSelector.SelectedItem.Text;

Comment: Yes when i watch the value, i'm getting a correct value.